# removing a div without a page refresh

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm loading data from a database via php with the following code:

```
<div>

<?php 
    echo "The subjects that you can tutor are:<br>";
    for ($i=0;$i<count($tutor_subj);$i++){
        $query_tutors = "SELECT level, subject 
                           FROM level, subject 
                         WHERE level.id = '$tutor_lvl[$i]' 
                         AND subject.id = '$tutor_subj[$i]'";

        $result_t = mysqli_query($db_conx, $query_tutors);
        while($m = mysqli_fetch_array($result_t)){
           echo "<div class='torem'>".$m['level'] ." ". $m['subject']." ".$tutor_top[$i].
                   "<div style='float:right; padding-right:5px;'>
                      <a href='#'>
                          <img src='images/remove_btn.png' onclick='removeSubj(".$log_id.",".$tutor_lvl[$i].",".$tutor_subj[$i].",\"".$tutor_top[$i]."\")'>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div></br>";
        }
    }
```

with the removeSubj function I want to remove this entry from the page but without a page refresh. At the moment the ajax call removes the entry from the database, but I need to do a page reload to see the change on the page - is there any way I can just have the entry fade away without a page refresh?

Here is the removeSubj function - can anyone suggest how I can achieve this?

```
function removeSubj(id, level, subject, topic){

   var con = confirm("Are you sure you would like to remove this subject?");
    if(con == true){
        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'php_parsers/removeSubjects.php',
           data: {
              "id": id, 
              "level": level, 
              "subject": subject,
              "topic": topic
             },
           success:function(data, response, xhr){

             if (response == "success"){
                 /*    window.location.reload(); */
             }
           },
           error:function(){
              // failed request; give feedback to user
              $('#ajax-panel').html('<p class="error"><strong>Oops!</strong> Try that again in a few moments.</p>');
           }
       });
    }else {
       donothing();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically you just need:

```
success: function (data) {
   $('#ajax-panel').html(data);
}
```

take the returned data and insert it into your div as html. if your server-side script isn't returning the data to be displayed, then just have jquery do it for you:

```
success: function() {
  $('#ajax-panel').text('Success!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a unique identifier on the div you want to hide. Adding the id to the div should work:

```
while ($m = mysqli_fetch_array($result_t)) {
    echo "<div class='torem' id='{$m['my_unique_id']}'>" . $m['level'] . " " . $m['subject'] . " " . $tutor_top[$i] .
        "<div style='float:right; padding-right:5px;'>
            <a href='#'>
                <img src='images/remove_btn.png' onclick='removeSubj(" . $log_id . "," . $tutor_lvl[$i] . "," . $tutor_subj[$i] . ",\"" . $tutor_top[$i] . "\")'>
    </a>
</div>
</div></br>";
```

Then you can hide or remove the div on success:

```
success: function (data, response, xhr) {
    if (response == "success") {
        $('#my_unique_id').hide();
        $('#my_unique_id').remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this but it does'nt work - could it be because I'm using the PHP to echo out the topics, so even once they're removed from the database, I need a page refresh to reload the new variables into the php from the server side?

Comment: You can remove whatever content you want from the client side using jquery. However jquery needs to be able to identify the content you are wanting to remove. Out of curiosity did you substitute a unique id in place of `my_unique_id` everywhere?

Comment: do you mean everywhere across the site? I need to check as i'm using the 'level,subject,topic' id's as the unique identifiers, so people with the same numbers will have duplicate ids